# Elegant way to handle "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" in Ruby for optional associations?

Tags: ruby, associations, try-catch, option-type

I have a scenario where I have optional associations. Sometimes the associations are there, other times they are not.

I run into a problem when I try to display the data on the screen (think a simple index action).

Consider the following application setup:

- Project has many Deliverables
- Project has many Deployment Records (two attributes of this model are 'name' and 'description')

I am interested in pulling a Deployment Record association from within the Deliverables Index Action.

I got it to work with the following code, but I find it somewhat ugly:

```
@array = deliverable.try(:project).try(:deployment_record)
if @array
   @array.each do |r|
   [r.name, r.description].join(' - ')
end
```

What would be a more elegant way to re-write this? I tried

```
deliverable.try(:project).try(:deployment_record).each do |r|
   [r.name, r.description].join(' - ')
end
```

but I keep running into the **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** error. I can't seem to find a way to gracefully get around the .each being called on the Nil Object. I have a feeling that somehow I should be able to do this more gracefully, but I can't put my finger on it.

I re-use this snipped many times through the code base, so those extra two lines are really killing me if I just copy and paste it everywhere. I am happy for the association retrieval to fail, I just want to fail gracefully without any errors or messages. Any ideas?

Comment: A bit hackish, but there's the `(@array || []).each {...}` option, or `@array.to_a.each`.  Unfortunately, the only way I can think to make the code truly pretty is to monkey-patch `NilClass`, and that sort of thing is usually frowned upon...

Comment: Thank you @XavierHolt - the **.to_a** option is probably closest to what I was hoping for. Four characters that will allow me to get away from the ugly solution. I will wait to see if anyone else has any better suggestions, and if not - post your comment as an answer in 24 hours and I will accept it :)

Comment: Will do.  I'm still hoping someone has a better answer, though - those are four extra characters I know I'd forget to type on a regular basis!

Comment: @XavierHolt since your answer helped me most - could you mind posting it as one so I can accept it? Cheers

Comment: There you go (totally forgot to do it like I said I would...).  Cheers!

Comment: If Ruby were a proper scripting language, it would just skip the loop when the value being "each'd" on was nil - but it isn't, so it crashes.  So, we must write extra code to check for nil before calling each.  The "to_a" works in some cases.  Otherwise, mess up your code with a bunch of "if" loops around every each in your often-nested cascade.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `to_a` method to make sure you have an array to work with (`nil` will yield an empty array):

```
@array.to_a.each do |item|
    #Whatever...
end
```

It's not the most elegant thing - you'll have to remember to add the `to_a` to your loops - but if you can't guarantee that `@array` is a valid enumerable, it's the simplest way to keep that code from crashing.

Answer (score 2):

In deliverable, `has_many :deployment_records, through: :project` Then when you ask for deployment_records, they will be returned as an empty collection.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Cheek. I've tried to simplify my question, so that it's easier to relate and has wider generic appeal. I tried to incorporate your answer in my actual scenario but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, continuing my accidentally submitted comment:

In my actual problem I have 4 models:

'class Component
  belongs to :deliverable'

'class Deliverable
  belongs to :project'

'class Project
  has_many :deliverables
  has_many :deployment_records'

'class DeploymentRecord
  belongs to :project'

Now, if I am iterating through Component record - how can I setup the following association to work?

'component.deliverable.project.deployment_record.each do |dr|'

In other words, I am 3 associations removed - is there a way to set "nested" :through associations?

Comment: Oh, and one final comment. What will happen when I make that call and Project model association has not been setup yet? I keep running into

"Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `deployment_record' for nil:NilClass"

unless I use Xavier's work around of converting everything to an array.